# Loop select, face creation, and extruding creating hollow surface

Tags: edges, extrude, loop

I have a face where I loop select, create a face, then extrude. However, whenever I do, it creates a hollow surface.

In addition, there are some weird artifacts left over from the extruding - faces still left over on walls as I extrude the face. This is seen when I try to extrude again:

[image]

[image]

Blend file should be available here: [image]

Comment: What precisely are you trying to do? - The faces of the  surrounding cylinder currently have 3 overlapping rings of faces as you can see if you go into X-Ray mode (Alt-Z) and Alt-select the rings of faces.

Comment: I'm trying to create a base for the structure by creating a face and then extruding downwards.

Comment: the bottom is messy, you have overlapping faces as John says, remove all the bottom and extrude down again, then fill with F

Comment: How do I remove the bottom? Do I remove all the faces on the bottom? Or can I somehow merge the faces?

Comment: Select all vertices -> F3 to search -> merge by distance should be able to do it

Comment: I selected both of the lower rings of faces with Alt-click in face mode then deleted them using X > Vertices. That leaves you with a single ring of faces and you can go into edge mode and Alt-click the bottom ring of edges. Then use G > Z if you just want the sides to be taller and F to fill the bottom face.

Comment: Allen's suggestion didn't work for me.  @john eason - Could you explain what you mean by lower rings of faces? Deleting faces on the bottom edges the way I tried ends up in deleting some structures from the main graph that I don't wan to delete (deleting the face removes a box for example)

Comment: Deleting any of the face or vertices on the bottom results in parts of my main structure being removed...

Comment: I guess you will still have quite a lot of manual work to do... looking at your object, the geometry is really a mess. Enabling _Face Orientation_ shows the lower base part is seemingly completely duplicated, with one set of faces with correct normals and the other with inverted normals. But also some faces in the upper part and on the numbers have inverted faces. Then when I select _Non Manifold_ edges it shows 22,255 of 95,225 edges. Selecting _Interior Faces_ it shows 14,951 of 48,139 faces. For the numbers I get 6,934 non manifold edges of 214,233 and 332 interior faces of 128,420.

Answer (score 0):

In <kbd>Face</kbd> mode, <kbd>Alt-Click</kbd> the bottom ring of faces:
[image]

Then <kbd>Shift-Alt-click</kbd> the ring above:
[image]

Press <kbd>X</kbd> > <kbd>Delete Vertices</kbd>
Then delete the remaining loose bottom face.

In <kbd>Edge</kbd> mode, <kbd>Alt-click</kbd> the bottom ring of edges.

[image]

You can move them down if you wish to increase the height of the sides, then use <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the bottom face.

[image]

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks. Hmm, did that create a solid base for you after extruding that final face? That was my issue. Extruding for me still moves the base up and down, but doesn't extrude.

Comment: I didn't use extrude at all. I just deleted the overlapping faces then selected the bottom edge loop and 'F'illed it.